# webdriver-test is unusable

Tags: phpunit, yii, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

On a virtual machine (clean, fresh Ubuntu server 11.04) I created a test website as described in [Creating Your First Yii Application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app) and now I want to create simple test using [webdriver-test](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/webdriver-test).

I set up proper TEST_BASE_URL in protected/tests/WebTestCase.php and created protected/tests/functional/MySimpleTest.php

```
<?php
Yii::import( 'ext.webdriver-bindings.CWebDriverTestCase' );

class MySimpleTest extends CWebDriverTestCase {

    protected function setUp() {
        parent::setUp( '192.168.57.1', 4444, 'firefox' );
    }

    public function testMySite() {
        $this->get( TEST_BASE_URL );

        $qElem = $this->findElementBy( LocatorStrategy::linkText, 'Users' );
        $this->assertNotNull( $qElem, 'There is no "Users" link!' );

        $qElem->clickAndWait();

        $this->assertTrue( $this->isTextPresent( 'test1@example.com' ), 'The is no "test1@example.com" text on result page!' );
    }
}
```

Running it looks like this:

```
etam@ubuntu:/var/www/test/protected/tests$ phpunit functional/MySimpleDbTest.php
PHPUnit 3.5.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 5 seconds, Memory: 5.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) MySimpleTest::testMySite
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: setBrowserUrl() needs to be called before start().

/opt/yii-1.1.8.r3324/framework/test/CWebTestCase.php:61
/var/www/test/protected/extensions/webdriver-bindings/CWebDriverTestCase.php:156

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Notice that it's complaining about setBrowserUrl() from  PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase_Driver, which is not the same as one from CWebDriverTestCase.

I tried to find out what's going on, but it's too complicated to me. It looks like problems with old and new selenium API existing together, but I'm not sure about it.

I'm using:

- Ubuntu server 11.04
- yii 1.1.8.r3324
- webdriver-test 1.1b
- phpunit 3.5.15 (repaired as described in bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpunit/+bug/701544)

Please help!

Comment: I'm having this issue also.  The setBrowserUrl method sets the $baseUrl property not the $browserUrl property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the setBrowseUrl() method right after the parent::setup() method because selenium requires this url to resolve relative paths on your test cases. So this way you could call open('full.url.com/someAction') or just open('/someAction') and both would go to the same page.